# Excel - Copying a Range (multiple Rows) and pasting and end of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a range sheet1 ("Assembly1") and paste it after the last row of sheet2.
I can find and identify the last row. I can copy and paste a single row. But I cant figure out multiple rows. I am not a programmer, I just adopt code, and I am guessing this is needs some form of loop that I cant fathom.

This code works for a single row range `(Range = "a3")`, but fails when its  `(Range = "a3:f3")`
I assume this is because I probably need to count the The range then paste it multiple times. But I could really use a hand with that.

```
Dim LRow As Long
        
LRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ag" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox LRow 'verifies I found the last row correctly

With Worksheets("sheet1")
.Range("assem1").EntireRow.Copy
End With

With Worksheets("sheet2")
.Rows(LRow).Insert Shift:=x1down

End With
```

Comment: Slight confusion. **1.** You want to copy a range or the entire row? **2.** Where do you want to paste the data in the 2nd sheet? At the end of the last row? If yes, then how will you calculate last row in sheet 2? Based on Col A or Col AG or some other column?

Comment: Yes, so, I need the entire row. Appears identifying the rows using a range "c3:f3" vs range c:f, work better for some things than others. It really doesn't matter to me in this case.

Comment: Hi 12 Monkeys, have you tried any of my macros below? they all worked for me. Please try and let us know.

Comment: you haven't answered my 2nd question but then i guess you have your answer so I will leave it at that @12Monkeys

Comment: David Wooley, yours don't work because I made an error in the question. The other response works fine (I am sure yours do as well, if I had not misspoken).

Comment: Siddharth Rout - I do have an answer. However, since you would like a response, #1 copy the entire row as defined by the range. #2 the data gets pasted on Sheet 2, last row, as identified by AG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you can just do this.

```
Dim LRow As Long
        
LRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("ag" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox LRow 'verifies I found the last row correctly

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    .Range("assem1").EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet2").range("A" & LRow+1)
End With
```

Comment: Mistake when I tried to simplify the sheet names. It is the  last row on Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?  Try either/have a play. **They are ALL working.**

This will work for any range you wish to copy paste over. Just change `"AG2:AG" & DLR` (the last row) to `"AG2:AI" & DLR` for example (done for you in the 3rd macro)

```
Sub cp()

Dim DLR As Long, WLR As Long
DLR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D100000").End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox DLR 'verifies I found the last row correctly

WLR = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D100000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG2:AG" & DLR).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & WLR + 1)

End Sub
```

or,

To appear more professional:

```
Sub cp()

Dim DLR As Long, WLR As Long
DLR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox DLR 'verifies I found the last row correctly

WLR = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG2:AG" & DLR).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & WLR + 1)

End Sub
```

I just took the code I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/7bln11/default_vba_paste_data_below_last_row_in_a/dpivpei/) and adapted it for your Sheet1 / Sheet 2 and Doing what you want. Its working.

3rd Macro:

```
Sub cp()
'Find Last Row
Dim DLR As Long, WLR As Long
DLR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox DLR 'verifies I found the last row correctly in sheet1

WLR = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox WLR 'verifies I found the last row correctly in sheet2

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG2:AI" & DLR).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & WLR + 1)

End Sub
```